# ADODB connection to an Excel file on SharePoint

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, adodb

I'm trying to get a adodb connection to a file on SharePoint (we have sharepoint 2013 as I know) to retrieve and upload some data to it from another excel file on my local drive.
I can do it when these two files are on my local drive with simple adodb connection, opening and so on. But I don't understand how to do the same with DB file being uploaded to SP.

I need some help to understand how to make it work.

I know I can open file from SP using VBA but in this case I can't make a adodb connection to it.
Thanks

Comment: ADO doesn't work over HTTP - you can maybe use the WebDav path instead if you have access to that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure about ADODB and SharePoint.  You may get that to work, but it may be more trouble than it's worth.  You can certainly CheckIn and CheckOut files!!

```
Sub CheckOut()
    Dim docCheckOut As String
    'docCheckOut = "//office.bt.com/sites/Training/Design Admin/Training Plan/adamsmacro.xlsm"
    docCheckOut = "http://excel-pc:/ExcelList.xlsb"
    Call UseCheckOut(docCheckOut)
End Sub

Sub UseCheckOut(docCheckOut As String)
     ' Determine if workbook can be checked out.
    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(docCheckOut) = True Then
        Workbooks.CheckOut docCheckOut
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to check out this document at this time."
    End If
End Sub
```

You can easily open and close Workbooks as well.

```
Sub OpenAndCloseWBFromSharePointFolder()

'If nobody has the file checked out
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("http://excel-pc/ExcelList.xlsb") = True Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the file on the SharePoint server
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the File to check if you already have it checked out
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

'See if doc can be checked in
If Application.Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").CanCheckIn Then

'Check In, Save and Close
Application.Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").CheckIn SaveChanges:=True, Comments:="Checked-In before Delete"

'Open the file again
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc//ExcelList.xlsb"

'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close
End If
End If

End Sub
```

You can even update values in specific cells!

```
Sub UpdateSpecificCells()

'If nobody has the file checked out
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("http://excel-pc//ExcelList.xlsb") = True Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the file on the SharePoint server
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc//ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever


ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 7).Value = 100
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 7).Value = 200
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 7).Value = 300


'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Save
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close

End If
End Sub
```

You can even create folders with VBA and list files and folders with VBA.  I'm curious to see if someone posts back here with an ADODB solution!  In the meantime, this may be worth a look.

https://scottlyerly.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/excel-geeking-using-vba-and-ado-to-pull-data-from-sharepoint-lists/